# What is the solution for Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration Vulnerability?

Tags: java, fortify

I have this Controller in Java:

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController extends AbstractController {

  @RequestMapping(value = Constantes.MAPPING_AUTH_BASE_ASP, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
  public String authenticate(@Valid ComunicationWithAspRequest comunicationWithAspRequest, BindingResult result,
      RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpSession sesion) throws Exception {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

When I scan my code in Fortify, the object comunicationWithAspRequest causes the Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration Vulnerability. Is possible to control which HTTP request parameters will be used in the binding process and which ones will be ignored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may refer to the problem [Prevent mass assignment in Spring MVC with Roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565342/prevent-mass-assignment-in-spring-mvc-with-roo).

In your case, you can use **@InitBinder** provided by Spring MVC. **@InitBinder** would specify the white list for json and bean mapping.

In my experience, I used **@RequestBody** for auto-binding. I need to add **@JsonIgnore** to specify the property that would not include for the mapping.

**SimpleController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/simple")
public String simple(@Valid @RequestBody User user){
   simpleService.doSomething();
}
```

**User.java**

```
public class User{
   private String name;

   @JsonIgnore
   private String dummy;

   public void getName(){return name;}
   public void setName(name){this.name = name;}
   public void getDummy(){return dummy;}
   public void setDummy(dummy){this.dummy= dummy;}

}
```

Comment: I was searching solution for same fortify mass assignment issue,  whitelisting and black listing is a tedious task for my application.Is there any other way to fix this other than spring @InitBinder ?

Comment: In my project, i just use a dirty way to solve this issue. ie. @JsonIgnore

Comment: I tried JsonView which works for my project more than JsonIgnore since the objects are used for more than 1 endpoint. Yet Fortify doesn't seem to recognize it

Comment: One more finding is that, Fortify is actually just to do scan to pop you warning. Some issue may not is solved, you just need to accept it with reason.

Comment: In my project, I have used something like @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

Comment: Could @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) fix the issue in fortify?

Comment: @BenCheng Is there any solution for spring boot application for this issue?

Comment: @nvm as I know, the same solution would be applied.

Comment: @BenCheng I have implemented InitBinder in controller and JsonIgnoreProperties in Bean, but still the issue in fortify. Is there any option to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

By adding **@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)** annotation on the class level the issue can be resolve in case we don't know what to ignore.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class className{

}
```